# Structure and Bootstrap'ing my RoR application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I have a Ruby on Rails Web application but the general 'look-and-feel' is a bit ugly.

I did some research and I found Bootstrap.

With research many question came to my mind:

- As I said before, I have a scaffolded RoR app. With the scaffold it generated the stylesheets for my application. It generated one application.css and files .css.scss for each controller. The application.css is used for the application layout, right? So for each view I want to style I need to create some view.css file in that directory? Because that directory only has .css.scss files.

So I'll have a general layout. My objective is: in every page of the site it appears the same "top-navigation-bar" and the same footer. So, the only 'content' that differs from page to page is the 'body' of the page. How can I do that? How can I just create in the applicantion layout the 'header' and the 'footer' and *leave* a "hole" for the body's of the next pages? How is that integration made?

That question is about the structure of the site.

Now, I need to know how can I incorporate the Bootstrap on my application. Should I make everything from scratch or is there a smooth way to do that?

My objective is to have the application layout struture and then use Bootstrap on it. How and where can I do that? And how and where can I apply some Bootstrap style to the other pages aswell?

I Know this is basic stuff, but I'm a bit lost with it and my site is really ugly.

Comment: Take a look at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: Yes. I understood the link to the styleseet, to the JS etc. But one of my questions is: If I make the header/footer here I only need to do <body> in the other pages and It will 'join' in the supposed place? I'm new to rails and I'm a bit confused.

Comment: See the `<%= yield %>` in `application.html.erb`? That is where other templates (your views) are substituted. Take a look at the source of pages in your browser, then look at your views, then look at `application.html.erb`, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Bootstrap in Rails I recommend gem bootstrap-sass (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), if you use SASS (default CSS preprocessor in rails).
Just add it to gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  #...  
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.0'
end
```

And include in application.css.scss manifest:

```
*= require bootstrap
```

At this point you may write pages and CSS stylesheets using bootstrap classes.
Usual scenario is to write your CSS in separate files and require them in manifest for concatenation (or include as separate `stylesheet_link_tag`)

For creating some panels, navbars etc that are common for site you may use layouts.
More about layouts in Rails - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts

For example, layouts/application.html.haml may be structured as follows:

```
%html
%head
  %title Rails app
  = stylesheet_link_tag "application", charset: "UTF-8", media: "all"
  ...
%body
  %nav.navbar 
    ...
  %div.container-fluid
    = yield
  %div.footer
    ...
```

In this case layouts declares HTML document, head with meta, links CSS (with Bootstrap) to pages and creates navbar, then renders page (with `yield`). Page contains only page-specific content and is selected by convention from controller name and method, e.g. controller `HelloWorldController` with method `index` uses view `views/hello_world/index.html.haml`:

```
%p
  Hello world!
```

To scaffold pages for Bootstrap use gem bootstrap-generators (https://github.com/decioferreira/bootstrap-generators).

**UPD. Some common information and example**

The result of combining layouts and partials with page specific content is plain old HTML document. This document can have only one `<body\>` and only this `<body>` can have representable content. Layouts in Rails give you ability to split HTML generation to parts - some things may be declared in layout, other - in pages. Using layouts you can wrap pages as you wish. But you should follow HTML structure and place visible content in `<body>`, including navbars.

Real world example is RubyGems.org, see:

- HTML page: http://rubygems.org/
- and it's source: layout - https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, page - https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/app/views/home/index.html.erb

Note that `index.html.erb` have no root element and uses `<div>`, `<h>` etc, because it generates just part of resulting HTML document.

`application.html.erb` declares all sections of document (`<html>`, `<body>` and `<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>` etc) and uses `= yield` where the current template (in our case `index.html.erb`) or it's part (where `= yield :part_name`) should be rendered.

More information about `yield` and `content_for` you can find here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: Imagine this point. I'll have the App.layout. There I only want to create the top-navbar and the footer ( to apear in all views of the site). So there (App.layout) do I need to create the <body>? Or I just need to create it in the other views? My main problem is that I'm not getting how do I create only the nav-top-bar in the layout and the body's in the other views and "insert" the body's below the nav-top-bar already created in App.layout. If you could help me would be great. If you want we can discuss this subject in other 'place'. Just let me know. Thanks! @AlkH

Comment: I updated answer with some common information and example. Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm getting it that is on app.layout that the structure of the page should be. But how does the index.html knows where to put the "information"? <%= yield :head %> what this tag does exactly? I know it renders the view. But, wich part of the view? How is that "connection" made? How can you say like: "Here you should present that content in the index.html page?" How does the index.html puts there the code?

Comment: Take a look at another page from Rubygems.org and you will see how it works, for example https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/app/views/profiles/show.html.erb. This page has content, wrapped as `content_for :title do ... end`, `:javascript` and not wrapped. So, in layout it will be rendered as `yield :title`, `yield :javascript` and `yield` accordingly.